# Convex Optimization Algorithm for Additive Matrix Decomposition

Tags: optimization, lasso, algorithms, matrix-decomposition

Given an m $\times$ n matrix $Y = S + L + E$, where $S$ is a sparse matrix, $L$ is a low rank matrix and $E$ is a noise matrix, I want to recover $S$, $L$. One of the techniques given in Agarwal et al (2012b) is to perform the following two step algorithm:

1. $\hat{S}$ = $argmin_{S \in \mathbb{R}^{mxn}}(\frac{1}{2}||Y-S||_{F}^{2} + \mu||S||_{1})$
2. $\hat{L}$ = $argmin_{L \in \mathbb{R}^{mxn}} (\frac{1}{2}||Y-L-\hat{S}||_{F}^{2} + \lambda||L||_{N})$

Note here that $||L||_{N}$ refers to the nuclear norm of $L$ (a.k.a the sum of the singular values of $L$). Though in theory, this all makes sense, my question is, how do I actually perform this optimization routine in practice (say on some software like R or Python)? I am working with image data, and so even if $Y$ is a 20x20 image, there are 400 free parameters to optimize over. Newton's method does not work here since the $L_{1}$ norm of $S$ is not differentiable, and neither did standard optimization functions like optim work in R. Agarwal et al just mentions off hand that "this convex program has an explicit solution based on soft- thresholding the entries of Y." I know what a soft-thresholding operator is, but I don't understand how to use that to perform the operation. Could anyone please describe a computationally feasible algorithm to perform the above optimization routines or refer me to a quick source that I can quickly read and implement? I apologize in advance for my lack of knowledge in optimization theory.